# ¿Cómo validar que un usuario está logueado con Firebase Authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

Tengo un proyecto hecho con Firebase y JS donde realizo login con 
Firebase Authentication, al loguearte pasas a otra pantalla, me di cuenta que si copio el link de mi nueva pantalla, cierro sesión y pego el link en mi navegador me reedirecciona a esa pantalla sin pedirme de nuevo login.

Traté con el firebase.auth().currentUser; darle una condición con un if saber si el usuario es nulo me mande al login y en caso de que sea correcto pueda seguir haciendo todo lo que mi código realiza.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user == null) {
console.log("usuario nullo");
window.open("index.html", "_self", true);


} else { //Usuario Activo  

//Codigo
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te muestra?

Comment: No es error, es cuestión de seguridad al iniciar y cerrar la sesión

Comment: Disculpa, el título de tu pregunta muestra "Error de currentUser..." y en el contenido mencionas haber intentado con `firebase.auth().currentUser` ¿no funcionó al hacerlo de esa manera o simplemente buscas una recomendación de alguna alternativa?,

Comment: Si funciono, la cuestión es que al hacer pruebas copie el link de la url de una sesión activa, enseguida cerré sesión en ese proyecto, luego el link que ya habia copiado previamente de la sesión activa lo pegue en una url y al reenviarme me enviaba a una sesion activa, cuando antes ya habia cerrado sesion, no tiene mucho que empece a trabajar con firebase. Por lo que pense que si cerraba sesion al volver a pegar ese link me volveria a pedir el Usuario y contraseña

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que le des una mirada a [este link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#onauthstatechanged), donde explican como utilizar onAuthStateChanged para verificar si el usuario está logueado, básicamente es cambiar el if que tienes por el siguiente código:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // El usuario está logueado, realiza acciones aquí
  } else {
       console.log("usuario nullo");
       location.replace("index.html");
  }

});
```

El listener se encargará de realizar acciones cuando el usuario está logueado o no, espero sea lo que buscas.